# Db_NoRecordExists error message is overwrite by ->addErrorMessage()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

My `Db_NoRecordExists`  message is overwite by `addErrorMessage`.
Code:

```
$emailaddress = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('EmailAddress');
$emailaddress->setRequired(true)
             ->setAttrib('size', '30')
             ->addFilters(array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'))
             ->addValidator('EmailAddress',TRUE)
             ->setDecorators($decorators)
             ->addErrorMessage('Please Enter Va`enter code here`lid Values.')
             ->setAttrib('MaxLength',100)
             ->setAttrib('onkeyup','setUserName()')
             ->setAttrib('onkeypress','setUserName()')
             ->setAttrib('onfocus','setUserName()')
             ->setAttrib('onchange','setUserName()')
             ->setAttrib('Maxlength', '100');

$emailaddress ->class="textbox";
```

and

```
public function isValid($data)
{
    $this->getElement('EmailAddress')
         ->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', false, array(
             'table'=>'puntermaster',
             'field' => 'EmailAddress',
             'messages' => array(Zend_Validate_Db_Abstract::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'A user with email address already exists'),
             'exclude' => array( 'field' => 'Sno', 'value' => $data['Sno'])
         ), TRUE);

   return parent::isValid($data);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information in question. What do you get, and what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a custom error message to your form element using `addErrorMessage()` or `addErrorMessages()` and one of the validators fails validation, *then the custom error message will be used instead of the validator specific error message*.

Only use `addErrorMessage` if you want to override all of the validator's error messages for a form element.

Another use of `addErrorMessage` is to call it after you've validated the form element and you want to add a custom message you later retrieve with `getErrorMessages()`.